# CSS background-issues in Mobile-Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera, mobile-browser

```
<div style="
width:100%; height:100%;
background-image:url('images/background.jpg');
background-position:center bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
">&nbsp;</div>
```

- background-position > no image displayed
- background-size:cover > stretching version

Comment: 1. Does the div parent has a fixed height? If not, you need to at least add `html, body {height: 100%;}` for percentage height to work. 2. Are you sure the image path is correct? 3. Which chrome version?

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing? Please be more specific.

Comment: ..all desktop browsers displayed correktly. [1] parent is body / html, body {height: 100%;} [2] path is correct [3] chrome 50.0.2661.89 & also similar in mobile-opera 36.2.2126.102826

Comment: [update] ..it is the picture - the picture causes the issue. but only at these mobile-browsers.

Comment: can you explain? what was the problem with the picture exactly?

Comment: the image size (5472x3648) was too large for Mobile-Chrome&Opera ..this was the reason for these symptoms.

Comment: What happens and what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The image size (5472x3648) was too large for Mobile-Chrome & Opera .. this was the reason for these symptoms.